# Write from one LDAP to another with C#

Tags: c#, ldap

I have a program that reads from an LDAP source, then writes a list of users and their attributes to a csv file. What i would like to know if its possible to read the users and their attributes from one ldap and write it to another ldap?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.ianatkinson.net/computing/adcsharp.htm) might be useful for you. Explains how you read from a ldap and writes to it

Answer (score 0):

This tool might be interested to explore the source code of for ideas: [LDAPadmin](http://ldapadmin.sourceforge.net/)

It is written in C#:

> Ldap Admin is free Win32 administration tool for LDAP directory
>   management. This application lets you browse, search, modify, create
>   and delete objects on LDAP server. It also supports more complex
>   operations such as directory copy and move between remote servers and
>   extends the common edit functions to support specific object types
>   (such as groups and accounts).